# How to rotate logs in laravel using logrotate?

Tags: php, logging, laravel-5.6, logrotate

Deployed my laravel application few months ago, and recently found out that my application was unable to write to log because my disk was full. When i checked i found out that the laravel.log file was almost huge. I want to know how to rotate the laravel logs with logrotate.

Comment: How does your current logging configuration (`config/logging.php`) look like?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to configure logrotate with php logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14145812/how-to-configure-logrotate-with-php-logs). There are so many answers regarding logrotate already. Please use the search before asking a question.

Comment: The file was _almost_ huge, XD.

Comment: @Mike Doe stop nagging and answer some questions - this question is straight to the point and first in a search.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Go to **/etc/logrotate.d** and create a new config file.

```
cd /etc/logrotate.d
sudo touch laravel_rotate
```

Add the log file location and some settings.

```
log/file/dir/laravel_log.log { 
    monthly 
    missingok 
    rotate 12 
    compress
    notifempty 
    create 755 www-data www-data 
}
```

Settings explained:

1. **monthly**: backups will be created monthly
2. **missingok**: ignore the file if it is missing
3. **rotate 12**: keep a year’s worth of backups
4. **notifempty**: do not rotate the log if it’s empty
5. **compress**: compress the log file
6. **create**: create a replacement log file with the following permissions

To test this new config, run `sudo logrotate --force laravel_rotate`

[logrotate doc](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate)

Comment: Great, also it is possible to rotate log files based on size.

Comment: @Yan is rotate better described as the number of backups to keep, so rotate 10 would give 10 weeks of backups if weekly (default) was set